# Flutter StatefulWidget getting value of dropdown button

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Dart, trying to pull a value from a DropdownButton widget but running into issues. I'm sure I am missing something.

```
class ChooseBagNum extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  _ChooseBagNumState createState(){
    return _ChooseBagNumState();
  }
  String get sValue{
    return _ChooseBagNumState.selectedValue;
  }
}

class _ChooseBagNumState extends State<ChooseBagNum> {
  String _value;
  String selectedValue='test';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
        items: [
          DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            child: Text('1'),
            value: '1',
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            child: Text('2'),
            value: '2',
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            child: Text('3'),
            value: '3',
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            child: Text('4'),
            value: '4',
          ),
        ],
        onChanged: (String value) {
          setState(() {
            _value = value;
            selectedValue= value;
          });
        },
        hint: Text('Enter number of bags'),
        value: _value,
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

The code that I am trying run using the Class

```
ChooseBagNum numberOfBags = new ChooseBagNum();
Print(numberOfBags.sValue.toString());
```

I get this error:
error: Instance member 'selectedValue' can't be accessed using static access.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you need to get that selected value from a parent widget. In that case, you should pass a callback function the receives a string. Then call that function in the `onChanged` event.

Something like this:

```
class ChooseBagNum extends StatefulWidget {
  // pass a callback to your widget to be able to get the selected value from a parent
  final Function(string) onValueSelected;

  ChooseBagNum({this.onValueSelected});

  @override
  _ChooseBagNumState createState() => _ChooseBagNumState();
}

class _ChooseBagNumState extends State<ChooseBagNum> {
  String _value;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
        items: [
          DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            child: Text('1'),
            value: '1',
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            child: Text('2'),
            value: '2',
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            child: Text('3'),
            value: '3',
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            child: Text('4'),
            value: '4',
          ),
        ],
        onChanged: (String value) {
          setState(() {
            _value = value;
            widget.onValueSelected(value); // call the function passing the value
          });
        },
        hint: Text('Enter number of bags'),
        value: _value,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I am getting closer using the call back function, but I am still having following error. This is the error I am getting: E/flutter (28636): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'call' was called on null.
E/flutter (28636): Receiver: null
E/flutter (28636): Tried calling: call("2")
E/flutter (28636): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)

Comment: Hi! In case you haven't solved it yet, can you show us how do you use the `ChooseBagNum` widget?

Answer (score -1):

List _categories = ['b', 'a'];
  String _selectedCategories;

add this code in body\

DropdownButtonFormField(
                      hint: Text(
                        'add your title'
                      ),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        isDense: true,
                      ),
                      value: _selectedCategories,
                      items: _categories.map((location) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                          child: Text(
                             location,
                          ),
                          value: location,
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedCategories = newValue;
                        });
                      },
                    ),